# Unresolved reference: Context in android MediaPlayer (kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer, android-music-player, soundplayer

I created this function to make the button do a sound when i click it, the sound file is mp3 located in `raw/button_click.mp3` directory .

```
fun play_sound(which_one:Int) {
    if(which_one == 1){
        val mediaPlayer:MediaPlayer? = MediaPlayer.create(Context,R.raw.button_click)
        mediaPlayer?.start()
}
}
```

But i get the following error when i run it `Unresolved reference: Context`

How should I edit my code to solve this problem?

By the way just ignore the if statement for now it always turns true for this stage of development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Unresolved reference: Context

You receive the following error because you are using the Class instead of your variable name as parameter.

```kotlin
fun play_sound(which_one:Int) {
    if(which_one == 1) {
        val mediaPlayer:MediaPlayer? = MediaPlayer.create(Context,R.raw.button_click)
        mediaPlayer?.start()
    }
}
```

There are also different kind of **Context**s in Android.

You have your Application, Activity, and Fragment Context, which is also tied to different lifecycles depending on what **Context** you used.

If this function is a member of your Activity.

```kotlin
fun play_sound(which_one:Int) {
    if(which_one == 1) {
        val mediaPlayer:MediaPlayer? = MediaPlayer.create(this@YourActivityHere,R.raw.button_click)
        mediaPlayer?.start()
    }
}
```

Fragment

```kotlin
fun play_sound(which_one:Int) {
    if(which_one == 1) {
        val mediaPlayer:MediaPlayer? = MediaPlayer.create(requireContext(),R.raw.button_click)
        mediaPlayer?.start()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

pass proper active `Context` to this method

```
fun play_sound(ctx:Context, which_one:Int) {
    if(which_one == 1){
        val mediaPlayer:MediaPlayer? = MediaPlayer.create(ctx, R.raw.button_click)
        mediaPlayer?.start()
    }
}
```

Comment: The same thing ctx doesn't work it outputs the same error message

Comment: @Adelgamer did you add it as a parameter to your method ?

Comment: if you start this method from `Activity` then you may pass `this` as `Activity` IS a `Context` instance ([extends it](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity))